# Branch versioning in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

We have a people that only use ArcMap. We have a project created in ArcGIS Pro, which obviously supports branch versioning.

How can we allow those using ArcMap to edit the ArcGIS Pro project considering ArcMap won't work with branch versioning?

Comment: This sounds like the perfect push to get those ArcMap users to bite the bullet and start using Pro. You are looking for a solution to an old piece of software not having the same functionality as its replacement, the solution is to use the new software if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks @TeddyTedTed. You are completely right but its not possible to force Pro on them yet, hence the need for a work around.

Comment: There is no work-around. Using branch versioning means ***not*** using ArcMap.